# Mousewheel

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery

Всем добра :)

Никак не могу справиться с глюком. Есть `jQuery`-код:

```
$(function() {
  var scroll_height3 = $('.small-present .small-listin-slider').innerHeight();
    var text_height3 = $('.small-present .small-banner-listing').innerHeight();
    if(text_height3 > scroll_height3) {
    $('.small-present .small-listin-slider').bind('mouseenter', function(){

    var val = -100;
    var percent = 100;
    //Вызов плагина
    $(document).on('mousewheel', '.small-present .small-listin-slider', function(event,delta) {

    //Счетчик положительное вращение(от себя)
    if(delta > 0) {
    val+=10;
    percent+=10;
    }
    if (percent > 100) {
      return false;
    }
    //Отрицательное вращение(на себя)
    if(delta < 0) {
    val-=10;
    percent-=10;
    }
    if (percent < 0) {
      return false;
    }
    //Вставляем значение счетчика в блок с id="result"
    $("#tall-slider .ui-slider-handle").css('bottom', percent + '%');
    $('.small-banner-listing').css('top', percent + '%');
    $('#tall-slider .ui-slider-range').css('height', percent + '%');
    //Отменяем действие по умолчанию (скроллинг контента)
    return false;
    });
  });   
  }     
});
```

Но когда колесиком мыши прокручиваешь в самое начало/верх, функция перестает выполняться. Mouseenter начинает работать снова, как только курсор выведешь из блока и снова заведешь. Mouseover или hover глючат и постоянно начинают работать со 100%. Как обойти это, не могу понять. Колесико мышки всегда должно работать, когда курсор наведен на блок.

Comment: @Romancho354, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

> //Отменяем действие по умолчанию
>
> ```
> return false;
> ```

Для этого используй это:

**event.preventDefault();**

п.с. пол твоего кода можно заменить на:

```
val += delta * 10;

percent += delta * 10;
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, так и сделал в результате в день вопроса - стало всё работать)) Ваш ответ, уверен, пригодится не только мне.